# Re-sample raster to acre grid using ArcGIS Desktop or R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, resampling

I have a 1m classified landcover raster layer that consists of values 1-4 representing various land covers.  I need to resample this layer to an acre grid.  Each acre in the resultant grid should contain the percentage of acre that one of the classification attributes (let's say value #1) comprises.

What's the most efficient way of doing this, considering my raster is quite large (>800 mb)? I assume it involves something like the zonal stats tool in ArcGIS Desktop, but I'm not sure.  I prefer ArcGIS Desktop or R solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not really resampling. Resampling would be converting all pixels in each grid square to whichever stat value (mean or max or whatever COUNTS not values since it's categorical data). But you want four values per cell, not one. It's categorical, so zonal stats won't work because it doesn't offer a count stat.

I believe you'll want [Zonal Histogram](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Histogram/009z000000w6000000/). Your first step is to create the one acre grid, which you would use the [Create Fishnet](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000002q000000) tool for (and make sure it's polygons). You can then use that as your zones in the Zonal Histogram tool.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a potential solution using R. Its runs quickly for a 1000x1000 raster. Not sure how it would scale to your 800MB file.

```
library(raster)
# Create a 1000x1000 pixel raster of land use classes 1-4 with some spatial structure
rmeter <- raster(nrow=1000, ncol=1000, xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=1000)
cosxy <- function(xy, T, A) {
    a <- 2 * pi / T
    return(A * cos(a * xy[,1]) * cos(a * xy[,2]))
}
rmeter[] <- ceiling(abs(cosxy(rasterToPoints(rmeter), 500, 4)))
# Throw in some NA values for good measure
rmeter[sample(ncell(rmeter), 10000)] <- NA
plot(rmeter)

# Aggregate to 1 acre resolution
# 1 acre = 4046.86 square meters 
acre <- 4047.86
# This functional returns a function to calculate % of cells that are a given value
# Required because raster::aggregate won't take additional args to agg function
pctCover <- function(val) {
    function(x, na.rm=T) {mean(x == val, na.rm=na.rm)}
}
# number cells covered by LC class / total non-NA cells
racre <- aggregate(rmeter, fact=floor(sqrt(acre)), fun=countCells(1))

# Or do them all at once
aggPctCover <- function(val, r, fact) {
    aggregate(r, fact=fact, fun=function(x, na.rm=T) {mean(x == val, na.rm=na.rm)})
}
r <- stack(sapply(unique(rmeter), FUN=aggPctCover, r=rmeter, fact=floor(sqrt(acre))))
names(r) <- paste0('lc', unique(rmeter))
plot(r)
```

**Example Data:**

[image: Imgur]

**Results:**

[image: Imgur]

Two notes:

1. This method calculates % 1m cells covered by the given land cover class excluding NoData cells. In particular, the numerator is number of 1m cells per 1 acre cell that are the given land cover class and the denominator is total number of non-NA 1m cells in that 1 acre cell.
2. This aggregates to approximately 1 acre resolution, you would then want to use `raster::resample` to get is to the exact resolution and alignment of your target grid.